# AWS Mobilehub: Swift 3 update, shows error at launchoptions

Tags: ios, swift3, aws-mobilehub

Since I updated my amazon web services app I created with AWS Mobilehub to swift 3 I receive the following error message:

[image]

As soon as I use "!" to remove the error my app crashes due to a fatal error:

[image]

Comment: Im pretty sure you need return something like       AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance.didFinishLaunching(application: application, withOptions: launchOptions as [NSObject : AnyObject]?)

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Mobile Hub console does not yet provide Swift 3 sample app code. The Swift sample app download can only be used with the legacy compiler setting in the Xcode project. We have received multiple requests for Swift 3 support, so we are working to prioritize it, but I can't provide an expected completion date at this time.

Comment: Still nothing after 3 month?

Comment: The AWS iOS SDK is fully Swift 3 compatible. The Mobile Hub sample app work to make it Swift 3 compatible is still in-progress.

Answer (score 0):

launchOptions is an optional.  If no shortcut is passed in, it will be nil.  Check the value before passing to AWSMobileClient like so...

```
if let launchOptions != nil {
  return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance.didFinishLaunching(application, withOptions: launchOptions!)
}

return false
```

Comment: The problem is that even if launchOptions is nil I need to pass it to this method.

Comment: In that case, create an empty launchOptions and pass it instead of nil.

Answer (score 0):

Modify 'func didFinishLaunching' method in AWSMobileClient.swift,

```
if (!isInitialized) {
    AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().resumeSession(completionHandler: { (result, error) in
        print("Result: \(result) \n Error:\(error)")
    })
    isInitialized = true
}
```